# How to count the repetition of the elements in a list python, django

Tags: python, django, list, count, django-taggit

I have a django app, I am using `django-taggit` for my blog.

Now I have a list of elements (In fact objects) that I got from database in one of my view as below

```
tags = [<Tag: some>, <Tag: here>, <Tag: tags>, <Tag: some>, <Tag: created>, <Tag: here>, <Tag: tags>]
```

Now how to find the count of each element in the list and return a list of tuples as below

**result should be as below**

```
[(<Tag: some>,2),(<Tag: here>,2),(<Tag: created>,1),(<Tag: tags>,2)]
```

so that I can use them in template by looping it something like below

**view**

```
def display_list_of_tags(request):
    tags = [<Tag: some>, <Tag: here>, <Tag: tags>, <Tag: some>, <Tag: created>, <Tag: here>, <Tag: tags>]
    # After doing some operation on above list as indicated above
    tags_with_count =  [(<Tag: some>,2),(<Tag: here>,2),(<Tag: created>,1),(<Tag: tags>,2)]
    return HttpResponse('some_template.html',dict(tags_with_count:tags_with_count))
```

**template**

```
{% for tag_obj in tags_with_count %}
   <a href="{% url 'tag_detail' tag_obj %}">{{tag_obj}}</a> <span>count:{{tags_with_count[tag_obj]}}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

so as described above how to count the occurences of each element in the list?
The process should be ultimately fast, because I may have hundreds of tags in the tagging application right?

If the list contains only strings as elements, we could use something like `from collections import counter` and calculate the count, but how do do in the above case ?

All my intention is to count the occurrences and print them in the template like `tag object and occurrences`,

So I am searching for a fast and efficient way to perform above functionality?

**Edit**:

So I got the required answer from 
and I am sending the result to template by converting the resultant `list of tuples` to dictionary as below

```
{<Tag: created>: 1, <Tag: some>: 2, <Tag: here>: 2, <Tag: tags>: 2}
```

and tried to print the above dictionary by looping it in the format like

```
{% for tag_obj in tags_with_count %}
       <a href="{% url 'tag_detail' tag_obj %}">{{tag_obj}}</a> <span>count:{{tags_with_count[tag_obj]}}</span>
    {% endfor %}
```

But its displaying the below error

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[tag_obj]' from 'tags_with_count[tag_obj]'
```

So how to display the dictionary in the django templates by like key and value?

Done we can change the above template looping as  below

```
{% for tag_obj, count in tags_with_count.iteritems %}
```

Comment: Honestly you don't need all this logic _just_ to show some object count. See: [Django annotation/aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try Python's [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

l =  ['some', 'here', 'tags', 'some', 'created', 'here', 'tags']
print(Counter(l).items())
```

Output:

```
[('created', 1), ('some', 2), ('here', 2), ('tags', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
x = ['raz', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'cztery']
wynik = {}
for i in x:
    if i in wynik:
         wynik[i] += 1
    else:
         wynik[i] = 1
print wynik

{'cztery': 1, 'dwa': 2, 'raz': 3, 'trzy': 2}
```

and, if you need:

```
import operator
wynik_sorted = sorted(wynik.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print wynik_sorted
[('raz', 3), ('dwa', 2), ('trzy', 2), ('cztery', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `count` and `set` functions look like they'd be of use here.

```
>>> l = ["i", "i", "am", "am", "am", "test"]
>>> list(set([(a, l.count(a)) for a in l]))
[('test', 1), ('i', 2), ('am', 3)]
```

`l.count()` provides the number of occurrences of the given item in the list. `set()` turns the list into a set (an unordered collection containing no duplicate items) and then `list` converts that set back to the proper type.

Since you're dealing with `Tag` objects, it's possible that you'd need to use some method to get their string representations (although I can't find documentation on their interface). Maybe something like this:

```
>>> l = [a.text for a in l]
>>> list(set([(a, l.count(a)) for a in l]))
```

Comment: Actually i want the tag object inside the template too(because i am using that in `url template tag as above`), so i am not using the string representation of the `Tag` obj

Comment: right - I think to use this method, you'd have to count repetitions of strings rather than Tag objects. After doing that, though, you could replace the elements of the list of tuples with the Tag objects themselves