# From a dictionary with repeated values, how to create a new one excluding the repeats and incrementing a counter inside the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

## Turn this:

```
a = {'1': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '1'},
     '2': {'name': 'Green', 'qty': '1'},
     '3': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '1'},
     '4': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '1'}}
```

## into this:

```
b = {'1': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '3'},
     '2': {'name': 'Green', 'qty': '1'}}
```

I was able to exclude the repeated values but could't increment the 'qty' field.

```
b = {}

for k,v in a.iteritems():
    if v not in b.values():
        b[k] = v
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to count the repetition of the elements in a list python, django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548710/how-to-count-the-repetition-of-the-elements-in-a-list-python-django)

Comment: That's a funny looking data structure you've got there. Indexes starting from 1, as strings, as keys. :) You probably have your reasons, but still!

Comment: Don't mind much about the indexes. The result could also be a list.

Comment: If you can alter the format of `a`, I'd certainly recommend removing the redundant index.  If not - @AndréLaszlo's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28045057/838992) is really nice.  It gets `b` into your format, but `result` is what you want without the redundant index.

Comment: You might be able to use `collections.Counter` from the standard library. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter
However, your data structure is not suited for the standard tools. If you had a list `["Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Green", "Blue"]` or a list of tuples `[("Blue", 1), ("Green", 1), ("Blue", 2), ("Green", 1)]`, it would be very easy to use Counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

# Summarize quantities for each name
for item in a.values():
    result[item['name']] += int(item['qty'])

# Convert to your funny format
b = {str(i+1): v for i, v in enumerate({'name': key, 'qty': str(val)} for key, val in result.items())}

# b contains:
# {'1': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '3'}, '2': {'name': 'Green', 'qty': '1'}}
```

If I could choose data structures, it might look like this:

```
from operator import add
from collections import Counter

a = [('Blue', 1), ('Green', 1), ('Blue', 1), ('Blue', 1)]
b = reduce(add, [Counter(**{x[0]: x[1]}) for x in a])
# b contains:
# Counter({'Blue': 3, 'Green': 1})
```

Comment: This answers the question! Even with the weird indexes. Thank you André!

Comment: I hope you could still help. Each key can have more values other than 'name' and 'qty'. It should be counted as a duplicate only if all values are equal.

turn this:
a = {'1': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '1', 'sub': ['sky', 'ethernet cable']},
  '2': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '1', 'sub': ['sky', 'ethernet cable']},
  '3': {'name': 'Green', 'qty': '1', 'sub': []},
  '4': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '1', 'sub': ['sea']}}

into this:
b = {'1': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '2', 'sub': ['sky', 'ethernet cable']},
  '2': {'name': 'Green', 'qty': '1', 'sub': []},
  '3': {'name': 'Blue', 'qty': '1', 'sub': ['sea']}}

Comment: I'll get back to you on that :-)

Comment: It gets a little bit more complicated since you want to do a deep comparison. Do you mind posting a new question that expands on your exact needs?

Comment: New question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049316/exclude-repeated-values-from-a-dictionary-and-increment-the-qty-field-accordin

Answer (score 2):

A cumbersome two-liner:

```
data = [v['name'] for v in a.values()]

b = {str(i+1): {'name': j, 'qty': data.count(j)} for i, j in enumerate(set(data))}
```

Following comments from André and the original poster, here is an even more complicated solution.

First, convert the original dict `'name'` and `'sub'` keys to a comma-delimited string, so we can use `set()`:

```
data = [','.join([v['name']]+v['sub']) for v in a.values()]
```

This returns

```
['Blue,sky,ethernet cable', 'Green', 'Blue,sky,ethernet cable', 'Blue,sea']
```

Then use the nested dict and list comprehensions as below:

```
b = {str(i+1): {'name': j.split(',')[0], 'qty': sum([int(qty['qty']) for qty in a.values() if (qty['name']==j.split(',')[0]) and (qty['sub']==j.split(',')[1:])]), 'sub': j.split(',')[1:]} for i, j in enumerate(set(data))}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice! But what if `'qty'` is not `'1'`?

Comment: Good point! Even more cumbersome, but this seems to work: b = {str(i+1): {'name': j, 'qty': sum([int(qty['qty']) for qty in a.values() if qty['name']==j])} for i, j in enumerate(set(data))}

Comment: Ridiculous number of edits - trying to work out to get the mini-Markdown code formatting to work! :-)

Comment: Funny, I've been coding Python for years but I have managed to miss dict comprehensions somehow. Thanks! Updated my answer too.

Comment: Thank you FuzzyDuck, it works perfectly. Now I actually forgot to say that everything under a key should be equal, not just the 'name'. The actual dictionary can have a 'sub' key which contains a list of items. These items should also be considered for defining if a key has duplicates. If you will, please see the comment on André's answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome! I would add to Andre's point that the data structure is not ideal, hence the fact that the dict comprehensions are getting ever more unwieldy. I've modified my answer above with something that seems to work.